Authentication needed when running Powershell scripts from the Azure Pipeline, but not from running Azure CLI
We are pushing out to Azure using an Azure DevOps Pipeline.
We are trying to run the following command as part of a task, inside of the azure-pipelines.yml file:
az ad app list --all
This works under Azure CLI without the need to login, but not under AzurePowerShell.
Here is the section from the YAML file for the Azure CLI task:
- task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Azure CLI - Deploy bicep files
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(serviceConnectionName)
        scriptType: bash
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        useGlobalConfig: false
        inlineScript: |    
          az ad app list --all

Here is the YAML section for PowerShell:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(serviceConnectionName)
        azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
          az ad app list --all 

When running under PowerShell, the error in the pipeline log is as follows:
ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.
I'm confused why this works under Azure CLI but not AzurePowerShell. Are we missing a parameter or setting that would fix this?
Any help gratefully received.
Thanks,
Steve.

Hi @Steve, Welcome to SO. I have shared some more documents to help understand the differences in the two command tool sets. Hope it may help resolve your query in this post and assist with your works to go. Good luck and cheers!

Please note that AzurePowerShell@5 task runs Connect-AzAccount command to authenticate service principal access to Azure NOT az login as AzureCLI@2 task does.
Azure CLI and Azure PowerShell are two different sets of command tools. In Azure PowerShell, you may try and use the Get-AzADApplication command instead to list AAD apps.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: Azure CLI - Deploy bicep files
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnectionName)
    scriptType: bash
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    useGlobalConfig: false
    inlineScript: |    
      az ad app list --all
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: Azure PowerShell - Deploy bicep files
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: $(serviceConnectionName)
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
    ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
    Inline: |
      Get-AzADApplication



Please also be advised to use different Azure CLI and Azure PowerShell commands for bicep template deployment.
Deploy resources with Azure CLI and Bicep files - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Learn
Deploy resources with PowerShell and Bicep - Azure Resource Manager | Microsoft Learn
